# Gradle: how to add an .aar its sources for androidJavadocsRelease generation?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, javadoc

I have an AAR (awesome-lib-extensions) file that is build as an extension of another AAR (awesome-lib) file. I have included the awesome-lib as a compile dependency. Everything seems to work: I can extend it, write unit tests for the awesome-lib-extensions, which work.

The problem that I have is the following: I cannot add the awesome-lib to my classpath for generating javadocs! How do I do this?
I currently have the following code:

```
libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        // title = ''
        // description = ''
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        //todo: add classpath here for javadoc!
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files, project.android.getBootClasspath())
        options {
            links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"
            linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference","${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
        }
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
    }
}
```

This does add any Android-dependency to the classpath, but not the .aar. How do I fix this?

Please note: the name awesome-lib is fictive, but it should make it easier to name everything.

Comment: It turns out that if I build again, then the sources are on the classpath during the second build. What should I do to make this work the first build?